# Change iptables log format

Tags: iptables, logs

Is it possible to change the log format of iptables ?

I want to add the `ssh_client` in the log.

I have already made an iptables rule for outgoing ssh

```
iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j LOG --log-prefix "outbound ssh ${SSH_CLIENT%% *} : " --log-ip-options "${SSH_CLIENT%% *}" --syn
```

But I want the variable `${SSH_CLIENT%% *}` to be dynamic and not static.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a dynamic `--log-prefix` when using `iptables`. However, since `SSL_CLIENT` holds the source IP address you could look in the `SRC="..."` field to obtain it.

Comment: No the SRC="..." is different than $SSH_CLIENT
And in the iptable log i want the SRC address and the $SSH_CLIENT
Because i want to know if a ssh session open another ssh session

Comment: i want to know if they are a solution to change the iptables log to add this information

Comment: @Hamza, can you please explain _in your Question_ why you're seeing `SRC` as different to the IP address in `$SSH_CLIENT`. Even with `ssh` over a tunnelled connection I cannot see how they would be significantly different.